# How do I to set multiple IP addresses on an interface in systemd?

Tags: debian, systemd, systemd-networkd

So in /etc/systemd/network I have a file lan.network:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=no

[Address]
Address=192.168.59.1/24
```

Sometimes I bring additional equipment onto that same interface but it's on a separate subnet (192.168.1.x).  To access this equipment I'd like to selectively run two IP addresses on the interface.  What is the best way to do this in systemd?

In older versions of Debian (Wheezy) I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and had something like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.59.1

iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
```

And so by default the eth0 interface would be enabled, and when I needed to get on 192.168.1.x I'd run:

`ifup eth0:1`.

Comment: I may have missed some changes, but I've been just using `/etc/network/interfaces` on Jessie all the time without thinking about it, and it seems that setting the alias IP address also works exactly the way you quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, to do this permanently, you simply pile all the addresses together, i.e.:

```
Address=192.168.59.1/24 192.168.1.5/24
```

Comment: Is there a way to selectively disable them other than restarting?  Otherwise this seems to work great.

Comment: I don't know how to do anything else with systemd, but you can always use the appropriate commands to manipulate the interface, eg: `sudo ip address add 192.168.1.5/24 dev eth0` and the removal `sudo ip address del 192.168.1.5/24 dev eth0`, and show current `ip address show eth0`.

Comment: Ah, I actually like that usage of `ip` better.

Comment: thanks meuh, using your 'ip address add' trick worked via a separate service, however, did you actually test the address=192... eth0.network config you posted? I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: @Kevin It is a long time ago, but I don't remember testing this, as I usually then keep an example test script or note for myself. It is probably wrong (I must have been taking the syntax from other options), but the other 2 things you tried in your answer seem correct, so when I can find some time I'll investigate and update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Arch Linux, SystemD 249.2-1, none of these (3) methods work ([tried this answer too](https://superuser.com/questions/775884/add-multiple-static-ip-addresses-to-a-server-with-systemd-networkd))

```
-------------------------
[Network]
Address=10.2.3.4/16
Address=10.6.7.8/16
-------------------------
[Network]
Address=192.168.59.1/24 192.168.1.5/24
-------------------------
[Address]
Address=10.2.3.4/16

[Address]
Address=10.6.7.8/16
-------------------------
```

Instead, using a simple SystemD service, you can set a second IP after boot... See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd) for more details on systemd service creation... Bonus point: this method allows you to have static or DHCP for the primary address.

- touch /usr/local/bin/second_ip
- chmod +x /usr/local/bin/second_ip
- edit file as per below

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ip address add 10.10.128.128/16 dev eth0
> ```

- touch /etc/systemd/system/second-ip.service
- edit file as per below
- systemctl enable second-ip

  ```
   [Unit]
   Description=second ip service
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   User=root
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/second_ip                                                                                      Type=simple

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```